# Como converter endereço em coordenadas no Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Preciso criar uma rota no mapa do Windows Phone. O local de partida é a localização do telefone, que eu capturo pelas classes Geolocator e Geoposition. O local de chegada é um endereço já premeditado, porém não estará em coordenadas (Exemplo: "Avenida Recife, Pernambuco"). Para poder inseri-lo no método para criar a rota, o endereço deve estar em coordenadas e não consigo achar um jeito de realizar essa conversão.

Segue um exemplo de como estou fazendo essa rota:

```
async void ObterLocalizacaoAsync(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    Geolocator localizacao = new Geolocator();
    localizacao.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    Geoposition posicao = await localizacao.GetGeopositionAsync();

    latitude = posicao.Coordinate.Latitude;
    longitude = posicao.Coordinate.Longitude;
}
void appRotaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ObterLocalizacaoAsync(latitude, longitude);
    MapsDirectionsTask rota = new MapsDirectionsTask();
    rota.Start = new LabeledMapLocation("Sua posição", new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude));
    rota.End = new LabeledMapLocation("Posição final", <coordenada-do-endereco>);
    rota.Show();
}
```

Comment: Você pode pegar as coordenadas de outro aplicativo como o Google Maps. Por exemplo, se você pesquisar por Avenida Recife no GM você vai encontrar a seguinte URL: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Avenida+Recife/@-8.1201743,-34.9202733,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x7ab1e95eecb6f7b:0x9b1d8bb39ab28ea3. Os Valores -8.1201743,-34.9202733 são a latitude e a longitude.

Comment: Se o usuário for fazer uma pesquisa textual pelo destino no próprio telefone, podemos usar algum componente de mapas e ler essas coordenadas do próprio componente. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx ou http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Acho que esse link responde a sua pergunta http://www.braincastexception.com/wp7-web-services-first-part-geocodeservice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível obter a coordenada GPS a partir de um endereço através do uso do método *FindLocationsAsync*.

Segue um exemplo:

```
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        // O valor 10 passado como parâmetro delimita o número máximo de resultados da busca
        MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync("Avenida Recife Pernambuco Brasil", new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()), 10);

        if (null != result)
        {
            List<MapLocation> locations = result.Locations.ToList();

            if (null != locations && locations.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Encontrado {0} resultados:", locations.Count));

                foreach (MapLocation location in locations)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: lat={1} long={2}", location.Address.Town, location.Point.Position.Latitude, location.Point.Position.Longitude));
                }
            }
        }
```

Encontrado **2** resultados:

**Nova Iguaçu**: *lat*=-22.7528499998152 *long*=-43.5015199799091
**Recife**: *lat*=-8.11838996596634 *long*=-34.9464200343937

Para entender mais sobre o uso de mapas em aplicativos Windows e Windows Phone acesse esse tutorial em http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/12/desenvolvendo-mapas-em-universal-apps